# getActiveRange returning a smaller range than expected

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple spreadsheet table with 20 columns, with an application that update rows on the first 14 columns. When one row is modified I am trying to capture the row using getActiveRange(). But I am getting 12 columns instead of the expected 14. No error. Just less columns than expected.

```
var ssPlat= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Plateau");
var aValues= ssPlat.getActiveRange().getValues();
var aCol   = ssPlat.getActiveRange().getLastColumn()

Logger.log("Columns:"+aCol+":"+aValues)
```

I don't want to hard code the range because more columns may be added later.
Please help.

Comment: If you want to get everything on a sheet use getDataRange() instead of getActiveRange() since this is only getting the range you select in the UI.

Comment: Thanks. But that's in fact what I am looking for: I don't want to take the full datarange. Only the first 14 rows

Comment: So what is exactly the issue? The selected range width is the length of the first element in the array, avalues[0].length isn't that what you get?