# getActiveRange returns wrong range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet, which is edited by external app via Google Sheets API.
Then, I have a Google Apps Script function in that spreadsheet, which is called by installable on-change trigger. In the beginning this function checks if `changeType` equals to 'EDIT', and then checks the last column of edited range using `getActiveRange()`. This works fine, but sometimes `getActiveRange()` returns smaller range, than it was actually edited.
Function code:

```
function myOnChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType !== 'EDIT') {
    Logger.log(`Wrong changeType: ${e.changeType}`);
    return;
  }
  var source_sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
  if (range.getLastColumn() !== 7) {
    Logger.log(`Wrong last column: ${range.getLastColumn()}`); // 9 line
    Logger.log(`NumColumns: ${range.getNumColumns()}`); // 10 line
    Logger.log(`SpreadsheetApp last column: ${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getLastColumn()}`); // 11 line
    return;
  }
  // Do some stuff
}
```

For example, we have empty range A3:G5. After inserting values in this range, it fills up properly (including G column), but `getActiveRange()` in the function returns range - A3:F5 (`getLastColumn()` and `getNumColumns()` returns 6 (9-11 line of code above), although order of column G is 7).

Why is this happening? I have about 30 sheets in this spreadsheet and this happens only on a few of them. Maybe number of rows on the sheet causes this somehow?

Also I found similar question, but it has no answer: [getActiveRange returning a smaller range than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965809/getactiverange-returning-a-smaller-range-than-expected)

**UPDATE 1:** 
To reproduce the problem, you need to do following steps:

1. Create empty sheet.
2. Add empty 1000 rows to initial 1000, so you would have 2000 empty rows. (I think this is the reason of the problem)
3. Add function from the above to this spreadsheet.
4. Add onChange trigger, that will call function from step 3.
5. Call the [API request to insert values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append). You can do it with "Try this API" section of [the page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vJSy.png) is an example of request parameters.
6. After step 5, in the sheet you should get filled row with the values from your request. For my example, it is a row in range A1:G1.
7. But `getActiveRange()` returns A1:F1 range and `getLastColumn()` is 6.

**UPDATE 2:** 
I think I found the margin. With 1539 or less rows (they can be empty) `getActiveRange()` works fine. If there are 1540 or more rows in the sheet, then this function will return wrong range: if 'F' column is included in the edited range, `getActiveRange()` will return range `[start column][start row]:F[end row]`. So, for example: 
if edited range is `A1:G1`, function will return `A1:F1`; 
if edited range is `E2:M5`, function will return `E2:F5`; 
if edited range is `F10:L10`, function will return `F10`; 
if edited range is `H3:N9`, function will return right range `H3:N9`; 
Need to mention that this issue appears only after [API call](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append), if the sheet is edited manually it still works fine. 
If you were able to reproduce this issue, please, let me know, that I'm not crazy.

Comment: You are aware that [API calls don't trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) the installable triggers either right? Does this happen when you manually edit the sheet?

Comment: @Aerials , No, triggers works properly with API for me. I think it's because of this [option](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption?hl=en)

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem. I get correct `lastColumn` every time I make changes. What do you mean 'this option'? Where is it used?

Comment: @Aerials , or maybe it's just the onChange trigger is the exception from that rule, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60929262/13230344)

Comment: @YuriKhristich , 'this option' is irrelevant to my question, it was the answer to question by @Aerials. I don't know how to reproduce the problem. It seems like almost randomly to me. Like I said in the question, `lastColumn` returns wrong value only on a few sheets that I have. What do you think about number of rows in the sheet? Can it possibly cause the problem? Can you try to reproduce it on the sheet with about 900 rows?

Comment: I've just make the sheet with 14x1000 cells. Everything works fine. It shows a correct number of last column of the range every time I make changes (delete, paste or edit cells, single cells and ranges)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your issue, and found that it has been filed in Googles Issue Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/189920154

Add a star next to the issue number to indicate that you are affected by it too.

Comment: It actually has a reference to this question, someone posted it there. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, here is the code I tried to reproduce the problem with:

```
// install the trigger
function createSpreadsheetChangeTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnChange').forSpreadsheet(ss).onChange().create();
}  

// main
function myOnChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType !== 'EDIT') return;
 
  var source_sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
  var lastColumn = range.getLastColumn();
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(lastColumn);

  // if (range.getLastColumn() !== 7) {  do stuff }

}
```

It works fine.

Comment: I finally managed to reproduce the problem. Added the algorithm to the question